# Does Visual Studio Express work well with Wine?

Tags: wine

I'm thinking of switching to Ubuntu as my primary OS,
but there's one big thing i'm still worried about.

For school we have to use Microsoft Visual Studio Express to program in C and C++ (i could just use any other IDE but this will be the IDE we have to use on the exam).

So i checked if Visual Studio Express is compatible with Wine and it says it is, however my dad (who used Wine in the past) says he really doubts it'll work decent.

Are there any people out there that have experience with Wine and VSE on Ubuntu?

Comment: As a general note, things tend to improve quickly sometimes in the FOSS world, so when someone says something about trouble they had "in the past", take it with a grain of salt. Just give it a shot and see how it goes -- it's free, after all. (Though posting on here was also a good idea!)

Comment: I've tried it some times ago, for my job. I had to stop for stability purpose. As TJ Ellis says: it's worth trying again, after some time. But you also should know that, if it works at one point, it may break some times later with a new update... So if you really NEED it to work flowlessly, it may be safer to make it run on its 'real' environment. Personally, I have a Windows VM for that purpose, and it works fine. But of course, your needs may differ from mine.

Comment: Nah ! Its just dont. Even Internet Explorer does not work well on Ubuntu through Wine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It [looks unlikely](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892) that it will work in Wine.

You have several other options:

- Dual boot - install Ubuntu alongside Windows and use Windows to run Visual Studio Express when you need to do school work.
- Install Windows in a virtual machine using [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or other virtualisation software. You can then install Visual Studio Express in the virtual machine and use that when needed.
- Use IDEs available on Ubuntu from the Software Centre in the `Developer Tools > IDEs` department:

  [image]

You may want to ask your teachers about using other IDEs. The code you write should work for any IDE unless it is platform specific or uses a particular GUI designer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, i'll try to run a virtual machine since i have some experience with VM's in Windows, can't be *to* different in Ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for specific Windows programs

see Wine's Application Database at http://appdb.winehq.org/ or http://wine-review.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the dv3500ea 's answer you can also download "[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)" that Microsoft offers for all platforms including Linux.