# What were the requirements for running Visual Studio IDE on Ubuntu? Can we develop IDE like it for Linux?

Tags: windows, wine, mono, ide, c#

I'm looking for deep knowledge for running Visual Studio IDE in Ubuntu. Can anyone tell me what were the requirements to do so. Ofcourse wine is a process available but as
It themselves says vs2019 run garbage. So is there's a way ???

Also mono is available but it's not supported latest .net framework and lots of missing features. They develop it already for prev framework but why not for latest framework?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) and [Does Visual Studio Express work well with Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/q/17902/)

Comment: Does on Debian we can run Visual Studio IDE? and does MonoDevelop has latest .net framwork available in debian ?  yes i've tried wine but installing VS IDE i got no luck